# Probability question about choosing digits between 1 and 9 and that their product is a multiple of 3

Tags: probability

Two digits between 1 and 9, inclusive, are selected at random. The same digit may be selected twice. What is the probability that their product is a multiple of 3?

I used this logic: if any one of the digits selected is 3, then the product would be a multiple of 3. There are 3 multiples of 3 (3, 6, 9) between 1-9, so $\frac{3}{9}$ = $\frac{1}{3}$, and since the second number can be anything, $\frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{1} = \frac{1}{3}$. Therefore, my final answer is $\frac{1}{3}$. However, the answer key used complementary counting and got a different answer ($\frac{5}{9}$). What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: $$P\left(3|XY\right)=P\left(3|X\right)+P\left(\neg3|X\text{ and }3|Y\right)$$ You missed the second term on RHS.

Comment: I assume you meant to say that if any of the digits selected is a multiple of $3$, then the product would be a multiple of $3$.  You did not account for which digit was a multiple of $3$.

Comment: You've counted the number of combinations if an element from {3,6,9} on the first place. What about the second place? For example, 8*3 also works.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are missing the case for which the first number is not a multiple of 3, and the second one is.

Another way to think about the problem is that the probability that the product is not a multiple of 3 is the probability that both numbers are from the set {1,2,4,5,7,8} which is 6 out of 9. This probability is (6/9)², so the required probability is 1-(6/9)² = 5/9

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Total number is: $9\cdot 9=81$ (9 possibilities for the first digit and 9 for the second).

Number of combinations that are not multiple of 3: $6\cdot 6=36$ (6 possibilities for the first digit and 6 for the second), 6 because from the set {1,2,4,5,7,8}.

Number of combinations that are multiple of 3: $81-36=45$.

Probability: $\frac{45}{81}=\frac{5}{9}$.

Answer (score 1):

> Two digits between 1 and 9, inclusive, are selected at random. The same digit may be selected twice.

In problems like this (with small numbers and just two independent variables), I find it often helps to draw a table and mark the cases being looked for.

> What is the probability that their product is a multiple of 3?

The product would be a multiple of 3 if *either* number is 3. I've marked those cases with the `x`s in this pretty little ASCII art table:

```
  123456789
1 ..x..x..x
2 ..x..x..x
3 xxXxxXxxX
4 ..x..x..x
5 ..x..x..x
6 xxXxxXxxX
7 ..x..x..x
8 ..x..x..x
9 xxXxxXxxX
```

You can eyeball count that as 6 lines of 9 `x`s, except that would double-count the ones where the lines intersect (uppercase `X`s), so reduce 9 for that. Of course you could count them in some other way to verify.

That gives
$$
P(\mathrm{product\ is\ multiple\ of\ 3}) =  \frac{6 \cdot 9 - 9}{9 \cdot 9} = \frac{5 \cdot 9}{9 \cdot 9} = \frac{45}{81} = \frac{5}{9}
$$

> I used this logic: if any one of the digits selected is 3, then the product would be a multiple of 3.
> There are 3 multiples of 3 (3, 6, 9) between 1-9, so 3/9 = 1/3, and since the second number can be anything [...]

That first part is right. Just that I think in the follow-up you missed that the *first* number can also be anything if the *second* satisfies the condition. Listing the pairs explicitly helps with that, and the table also exposes the overlapping cases.

---

Practice problem: What's the probability if we change the problem so that the two digits can't be the same? (It's not the same, by my count.)